# How to use decode in sql-loader?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I use sqlldr to import CSV files and I have some problem with date multiple formats.

Dates inside the CSV file are **DD/MM/YYYY** and if **there is no date it is a single dot**

---

### CSV file

---

```
DATE_COLUMN;OTHER_COLUMN
01/01/2013;other column content 1
.;other column content 2
```

---

### My .ctl file for sqlldr

---

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/path/to/my/file.csv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE table_to_fill
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
(
COLUMNDATE "decode(:COLUMNDATE ,NULL,'.', to_date(:COLUMNDATE ,'DD/MM/YYYY'))",
OTHER_COLUMN
)
```

The import is working when I use :

```
decode(:COLUMNDATE ,NULL,'.'))
```

or

```
to_date(:COLUMNDATE ,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

But not when I try to combine both...

Here is the error log :

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table table_to_fill, column COLUMNDATE.
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

How can I combine these, please ?

I thought that the last parameter of the "decode" function was for the default value of the column, am I wrong ?

Comment: May be switch `.` with `null` because value to compare with must come first in `decode`? `decode(:COLUMNDATE ,'.',NULL, to_date(:COLUMNDATE ,'DD/MM/YYYY'))`

Comment: I've tried before because I thought like you, but every example I've seen was written this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Loader's "regular" syntax should be enough here. Try this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/path/to/my/file.csv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE table_to_fill
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
(
  COLUMNDATE DATE(7) "DD/MM/YYYY" NULLIF COLUMNDATE = "."
  OTHER_COLUMN
)
```