# How to use to_number and nullif in sql-loader?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I've had a similar problem with dates (combination of to_date and nullif) here : [How to use decode in sql-loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130689/how-to-use-decode-in-sql-loader)

And it was solved nicely.

My problem is that a numeric field in my CSV file can have these formats : 999,999,999.99 or just a dot '.' for null values.

This is **working** :

```
MINQUANTITY      "TO_NUMBER(:MINQUANTITY, '9999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')"
```

or

```
MINQUANTITY      NULLIF MINQUANTITY      = '.'
```

---

But it is **not working** when I'm trying to combine both :

```
MINQUANTITY      "TO_NUMBER(:MINQUANTITY, '9999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')  NULLIF :MINQUANTITY= '.'"
```

Here is the error log :

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table MY_TABLE, column MINQUANTITY.
ORA-00917: missing comma
```

How can I combine these ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NULLIF` condition should not be inside the double-quotes for the SQL string; and it needs to come first. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#i1008150):

> - The SQL string appears after any other specifications for a given column.
> - The SQL string must be enclosed in double quotation marks.
>
> ...
>
> - The SQL string is evaluated after any NULLIF or DEFAULTIF clauses, but before a date mask.

So it should be:

```
MINQUANTITY NULLIF MINQUANTITY = '.'
  "TO_NUMBER(:MINQUANTITY, '9999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')"
```

(You can split into two lines for readability, both parts still apply to the `MINQUANTITY field).

In the log that's reported as:

```
MINQUANTITY                          NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER
    NULL if MINQUANTITY = 0X2e(character '.')
    SQL string for column : "TO_NUMBER(:MINQUANTITY, '9999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')"
```

(Have you got your NLS chars the right way round? This is treating `,` as the decimal separator, while your question suggests you're using `.`. Either will work as long as the value is enclosed in double-quotes, of course).

Comment: It works ! Thanks. And for NLS, you seem to be right too. Thanks again.