# How to replace a comma (',') with a period ('.') while loading using sql loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have number(20,4) field for which the data is coming in the following format :

```
120,24
200,45
```

I want to insert it into a table in the following format :

```
120.24
200.45
```

Below is the control file :

```
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE TEMP_TARIFICACION_FIJA_69
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ID EXPRESSION "TARIFICACION_FIJA_69_SEQ.nextval",
TIPO,
SECTARIFA,
IDFECTAR,
IDGRPDES,
IDCLAISDEST,
IDTIPUSO,
IDTIPHOR,
MONTO "REPLACE (:MONTO,',','.')",
IDOPERADOR,
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE "SYSDATE"
)
```

I want to replace the field MONTO. I am trying with the above control file but it is not working.
How can I achieve this ? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the original data in a different culture/locale than the desired format?  I ask because you may also need to convert 1.120,24 to 1,120.24 (or 1120.24).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
monto    "TO_NUMBER(:monto,'999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')",
```

Comment: Ehh. Sorry. Maybe these examples could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143888/how-to-use-to-number-and-nullif-in-sql-loader http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1144 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options072.htm#OLADM413

Answer (score 0):

try this 
`monto "to_number(replace(:nilai_pph,',','.'))"`